# How to use an operator in where clause with an include?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following Model:

```
AuthorModel.hasMany(BookModel);
BookModel.belongsTo(AuthorModel);
```

I want to select an author whose name or the title of one of his books matches the search string.

Something like:

```
            Author.findOne({
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { name: 'test'},
                        {'books.title':'test'}
                    ]
                },
                include: [{
                    model: Book
                }]
            })
```

Whatever I try, I always end up with: `Unknown column 'books.title' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the `where` clause inside your `include`.

```
Author.findOne({
  include: [{
    model: Book,
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { '$author.name$': 'test'},
        { title: 'test'}
      ]
    },
  }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out, but the author columns have to be addressed correctly. Also maybe you could describe in which cases the where clause has to be at which place. For me, it is still extremely confusing. For example, if working the other way round, and selecting the book including author, in most cases a where clause within the include is useless. It has to be placed outside the include and the author columns have to be addressed within that where clause.